# how to change the css of button based on menustrip item click windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I have five button and a menu strip, I want to apply the color on button based on the menustip click.

Suppose I have btn1, btn2, btn3, and menu stip which items are Test1, Test2, and Test3.
When I click on Test1 then btn1 color should become orange, when I click Test2 and btn1 color become white and btn2 color become orange, same as Test3.

some one please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the events of your Menu strip Items and you can do the following to change the color of buttons...

```
private void Test1ItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
}

private void Test2ItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1.BackColor = Color.White;
    btn2.BackColor = Color.Orange;
}
```

Remember **There is no css for buttons in win forms**.

**Updated:**

```
void ChangeColor(string menuItem)
{
  switch(menuItem)
  {
    case "Test1":
      btn1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
      break;
    case "Test2":
      btn1.BackColor = Color.White;
      btn2.BackColor = Color.Orange;
      break;
     // and so on
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to create a generic method.. how could I do with the help of that